# Sequential Dynamic filters on the same Spark Dataframe Column in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a column named root and need to filter dataframe based on the different values of a root column.

Suppose I have a values in root are parent,child or sub-child and I want to apply these filters dynamically through a variable.

```
val x = ("parent,child,sub-child").split(",")
x.map(eachvalue <- {

   var df1 = df.filter(col("root").contains(eachvalue))

}
```

But when I am doing it, it always overwriting the DF1 instead, I want to apply all the 3 filters and get the result.

May be in future I may extend the list to any number of filter values and the code should work.

Thanks,
Bab

Comment: what's the type of root column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply the subsequent filters to the result of the previous filter, not on `df`:

```
val x = ("parent,child,sub-child").split(",")
var df1 = df
x.map(eachvalue <- {
    df1 = df1.filter(col("root").contains(eachvalue))
}
```

`df1` after the map operation will have all filters applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see an example with spark shell. Hope it helps you.

```
scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> val df0 = 
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(1,2,1,3,3,2,1)).toDF("number")
df0: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [number: int]

scala> val list = List(1,2,3)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)


scala> val dfFiltered = for (number <- list) yield { df0.filter($"number" === number)}
dfFiltered: List[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] = List([number: int], [number: int], [number: int])

scala> dfFiltered(0).show
+------+
|number|
+------+
|     1|
|     1|
|     1|
+------+


scala> dfFiltered(1).show
+------+
|number|
+------+
|     2|
|     2|
+------+


scala> dfFiltered(2).show
+------+
|number|
+------+
|     3|
|     3|
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `isin` can be used in this case below is the example.

```
import spark.implicits._

val colorStringArr = "red,yellow,blue".split(",")
val colorDF =
  List(
    "red",
    "yellow",
    "purple"
  ).toDF("color")
// to derive a column using a list
colorDF.withColumn(
  "is_primary_color",
  col("color").isin(colorStringArr: _*)
).show()


     println( "if you don't want derived column and directly want to   filter using a list with isin then .. ")
    colorDF.filter(col("color").isin(colorStringArr: _*)).show
```

---

Result :

```
+------+----------------+
| color|is_primary_color|
+------+----------------+
|   red|            true|
|yellow|            true|
|purple|           false|
+------+----------------+
```

if you don't want derived column and directly want to filter using a list with isin then ....

```
+------+
| color|
+------+
|   red|
|yellow|
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way using array_contains and swapping the arguments.

```
scala> val x = ("parent,child,sub-child").split(",")
x: Array[String] = Array(parent, child, sub-child)

scala> val df = Seq(("parent"),("grand-parent"),("child"),("sub-child"),("cousin")).toDF("root")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [root: string]

scala> df.show
+------------+
|        root|
+------------+
|      parent|
|grand-parent|
|       child|
|   sub-child|
|      cousin|
+------------+


scala> df.withColumn("check", array_contains(lit(x),'root)).show
+------------+-----+
|        root|check|
+------------+-----+
|      parent| true|
|grand-parent|false|
|       child| true|
|   sub-child| true|
|      cousin|false|
+------------+-----+


scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my two cents

```
val filters = List(1,2,3)
val data = List(5,1,2,1,3,3,2,1,4)
val colName = "number"
val df = spark.
  sparkContext.
  parallelize(data).
  toDF(colName).
  filter(
     r => filters.contains(r.getAs[Int](colName))
  )

df.show()
```

which results in

```
+------+
|number|
+------+
|     1|
|     2|
|     1|
|     3|
|     3|
|     2|
|     1|
+------+
```